# Bloquear páginas usando login e session

Tags: php, segurança

Estou a desenvolver um site que tem um painel administrativo.
Esse painel tem um login, o meu problema é que eu consigo entrar dentro do painel através do link, ou seja não está seguro, qualquer pessoa é capaz de entrar se souber o nome dos ficheiros. Exemplo:

```
http://localhost/om/admin/Painel.php
```

Se eu fizer isto entra me no site e consigo realizar tudo sem ser administrador, pra corrigir isto sei que pode ser feito com *session*, mas não sei como fazer.

Não tenho qualquer código, apenas tenho um ficheiro chamado _config.php que está a ser chamado em todos os ficheiros do painel.

Comment: Aconselho antes de criar uma dúvida  dar uma pesquisada no StackOverFlow pois o mesmo já possui várias respostas para este problema, veja uma resposta minha por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70758/acesso-somente-via-login-e-senha-inibindo-acesso-direto-via-url/70765#70765

Answer (score 2):

No arquivo que verifica as informações do usuário, armazene o ID do usuário em uma sessão.

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão

// Pega os dados do usuário
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT usuarioId FROM usuarios WHERE login = ? AND senha = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $senha);
$stmt->execute()
$res = $stmt->get_result();

// Verifica se encontrou o usuário
if ($res->num_rows){
    $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['usuarioId']; // Marca a global para verificar se o usuário está logado.
    header('Location: http://localhost/sitema/inicio.php'); // Página do sistema
    exit; // Encerra a execução do script
} else {
   // Se não encontrou o usuário, manda de volta para o form de login
   header('Location: http://localhost/sitema/login.php'); // Página do sistema
   exit; // Encerra a execução do script
}
```

Crie o arquivo: `restrito.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
// Se o usuário não está logado, manda para página de login.
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header("Location: http://localhost/sistema/login.php");
exit; // Encerra a execução do script
```

Inclua o arquivo no inicio de todas as páginas que você quer bloquear para quem não esteja logado.

**Atenção**: O arquivo `restrito.php` deve ser a primeira expressão da sua página, antes de qualquer outra coisa. Exemplo:

```
<?php require_once('caminho/para/restrito.php');?><DOCTYPE html>...
```

Não pode ter nem mesmo um  (espaço) em branco antes.

Comment: dá tudo o unico problema é que ao fazer login com os dados certos aparece na mesma a mensagem que nao tenho permissao

Comment: A sua consulta ao banco está trazendo os dados certo? Caso sim, você registrou ali nas variáveis `$_SESSION` depois da consulta que o usuário está logado? Poste o seu código aqui para vermos o que está dando errado, o arquivo que faz a consulta, o arquivo de restrição e um arquivo de página. Assim podemos analisar melhor o problema.

Comment: O código que tenho é o que está acima, o problema é que a coluna para fazer o login nao deve de estar preparada para arrays, nao da para fazer outra maneira mais simples sem ser a que esta em cima, esse array

Comment: Dei uma simplificada ali no código, se ainda estiver com dificuldades deixe-nos saber. A forma de fazer é usando Session mesmo, poderia usar Cookies mas acredito que é mais complicado, e não necessário. A variável `$_SESSION`, nada mais é do que um `array` global, para a utilização delas você sempre tem que declarar o `session_start()` no início do código, tem que ser sempre a primeira coisa (com raras exceções).

Comment: isto diz que tenho um ciclo de redireccionamento

Comment: verifica se o arquivo `restrito.php` está sendo incluído na página de login, no caso a página que tem o formulário para login. Ali não pode ser restrito, senão o usuário nunca vai conseguir entrar no sistema.

Comment: é assim eu tenho 2 ficheiros( um que tem o form do login) e outro ficheiro que tem a ligaçao do login a base de dados as verificações e isso tudo, onde tenho de meter isto : <?php
session_start();

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT usuarioId FROM usuarios WHERE login = {login} AND senha = {$senha}");

if (count($resultado)>0){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $resultado[0]['usuarioId'];
} é nesse ficheiro do login que ta a fazer as verificaçoes ... á base de dados certo?

Comment: Isso, correto, e se não encontrar o usuário tu redireciona pro form de novo. Se encontrar tu redireciona pra página do sistema.

Comment: Atualizei o código ali, com alguns detalhes que ficou faltando, também comentei ele pra tu entender melhor o processo, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Este problema é bem comum e cabe a você definir quem pode acessar a pagina ou não.
O exemplo do @Carlos ilustra bem como solucionar o problema.

A lógica por tras disso é:
Todos os usuários tem acesso a todas as páginas de sua aplicação, portanto você deve definir um nivel de acesso a cada um. Neste exemplo acima o sugerido foi testar se o usuário já fez login anteriormente e permitir o acesso. Caso não tenha feito login ele da uma mensagem de erro.
Muitos web-sites redirecionam o usuário para a tela de login novamente caso o usuario não tenha permissão.

Lhe recomendo ler a função [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) do php.
Com esta função você pode redirecionar o usuário a outra página.

Observações importantes:

1. Lembre-se que quando for utilizar sessão você sempre deve chamar a função [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) antes de trabalhar com a variavel super global $_SESSION;
2. Quando for utilizar a função [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) para redirecionar um usuário você deve tomar o cuidado para não mandar nenhuma saida (output) para o navegador, seja ela um espaço, um enter, ou uma tag HTML qualquer.

Answer (score 1):

Tomei a liberdade de criar este início de classe que vai de encontro ao indicado.

desta forma no futuro será incluída toda a lógica necessária para o teu projeto adicionando um método a classe.

É um inicio....

```
class Auth {

    public static function handleLogin(){
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {

            header('location: ' . URL);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

No início de cada página basta colocar...

```
Auth::handleLogin
```

Para poder funcionar tem de ser iniciada variável URL por exemplo...

```
define('URL', 'http://localhost/');
```

E assim que as credenciais sejam validadas deverá :

```
$_SESSION['user_logged_in']=true;
```

Comment: gostaria de falar consigo pessoalmente, seria possivel?

Comment: Coloque a sua questão... tenho todo o prazer em Ajudar! Se gostou da resposta não se esqueça de votar... É assim que está comunidade funciona.

Comment: Eu sou novo nisto, e estas respostas todas me deixaram confuso

Comment: Opa, @cloud, a resposta do chambelix é boa, você pode usar no lugar do arquivo `restrito.php`. Apesar de que pra quem está iniciando pode ser um pouco confuso. Eu estou fazendo um "mini curso" sobre programação orientada a objetos, criando justamente um painel de administração, se quiser acompanhar no blog [Devcia](http://devcia.com/category/series/phpoo-na-pratica/)

Comment: Tudo bem...por chat room?

Comment: Deixe estar, não o quero incomodar, isto de qualquer das maneiras tem que ir, voces ja me ajudaram bastante eu vou vendo por mim e testando o que da errado e o que da certo, obrigado pessoal

Comment: Tudo bem... Já agora se quiser fazer uma validação específica diga... Queria também recomendar a criação de uma classe para lidar com o Session... Se está a começar leia e entenda as classes em php pois vai ser muito útil.

Comment: o problema é depois aplicar no site ... mas devagar se vai ao longe ^^

Comment: Pelo que apresentei ao aplicar em produção o URL tem de ser o domain... Ou seja substituir o localhost pelo dominio. No entanto para colocar em produção uma versão bem mais melhorada deveria de acontecer.

Answer (score 0):

Quando efetua o login joga as informações em uma session depois em todas as páginas verifica se existe a session antes de exibir a página caso contrario redireciona para o login.

Obs.: Caso não tenha ficado claro me avisa que complemento.

Comment: é assim eu nao percebo muito de session
o login funciona vai a bd verificar os valores ....
o que eu quero é nao entrar no painel atraves do link :s