# Acesso somente via login e senha, Inibindo acesso direto via url

Tags: php, html

fiz um sistema de login de acesso, mas gostaria que o usuario fosse obrigado a acesa-lo com o login e senha, inibindo o acesso direto via url.

Qualquer pessoa pode acessar a pagina via URL digitando o endereço. Gostaria de inibir esse tipo de acesso, fazendo que o usuário somente pudesse acessar a página via login e senha!

Estarei adicionando os códigos criados a baixo:

Código do Login:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['logado'] = 1;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><?php include "../conexao.php"; ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Painel Adm. - Login</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_login/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
$logotipo = $_POST['logotipo']; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topo");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<div id="logo" class="form bradius">
<div align="center" class="logo"><img src="../upload/<?php echo $res['logotipo'] ;?>" width="auto" height="58" /></div>
<div class="acomodar">
<form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="login">Login: </label><input id="login" type="text" class="txt bradius" name="login" value="" />
<label for="senha">Senha: </label><input  id="senha" type="password" class="txt bradius" name="senha" value="" />
<input type="submit" class="sb bradius" name="enter" value="Entrar" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'");
$conta = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($conta == '0'){
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Usuario e senha nao corresponde!');</script>";
}else{

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $res ['id'];
$nome = $res ['nome'];
$login = $res ['login'];
$senha = $res ['senha'];
$nivel = $res ['nivel'];

if($nivel == 'admin'){
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/painel/index.php?login=$login&senha=$senha';</script>";
}else{
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Erro ao acessar seu Painel Admin.!');</script>";
}}}}
?>

<!--acomodar-->
</div>
<!--login-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Página a ser inibida ao acesso direto via URL:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logado']) || $_SESSION['logado'] !== 1){
header("Location: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/index.php");   
} else { 
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$idusername = $_SESSION['iduser'];
session_destroy();
exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 10 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="#.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;">

<div id="container" style="
background-color: #FF6;
width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
text-align: left;">

<br>
Menu
<br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se os amigos puderem me ajudar a inibir o acesso direto via URL, ficarei muito grato.

Um BRIGADÃO a todos pela atenção.

Comment: Estude sobre SQLInjection e PDO, sobre a sessão é lógica pura. Procure ver exemplos no youtube... Um exemplo de uma falha de SQLInjection no seu sistema é ... Coloque no usuario isso -> admin' OR 1=1#

Comment: Depois coloque uma senha qualquer e vc tera acesso ao sistema.

Comment: Para inibir o acesso como vc perguntou, coloque embaixo do location um die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ao logar você inicia a sessão colocando `$_SESSION['logado'] = 1` basta 
você colocar em um arquivo `funcoes.php` aonde as suas paginas vão chama-las,
e executar uma função por exemplo:

```
function validaAcesso($usuario){
   if(empty($usuario)):
      header("Location: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/index.php");
   endif;
}

validaAcesso($_SESSION['logado']);
```

Se a sessão estiver vazia ele não logou pelo painel, então redirecione ele.

você pode aplicar a mesma ideia para o botão de desconectar do painel

```
function desconectar(){
   session_unset();
    header("Location: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/index.php");
}
```

clicou, removeu a sessão e voltou para o login, claro há n formas de fazer mas essa te da uma boa ideia de como prosseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, é mais menos isso:

Ou vc faz uma função que verifica se existe uma sessão com o usuário logado, ou vc inclui o código de verificação em cada página que vc n quer q seja acessada diretamente.

Na logica, vc verifica se o usuário inserido no formulário é igual ao do bd, assim como a senha também. Se for true, cria a sessão e redireciona para a página a ser acessada, se for false vc destrói a sessão e redireciona para a página de login.

Espero ter ajudado.

if($userp == $user && $passp == $pass) {

```
    $_SESSION['user'] = $userp;
                        $_SESSION['pass'] = $passp;
                        header('Location: inserir.php');
                        exit(); 
                   }else{
                        unset($_SESSION['user']);
                        unset($_SESSION['pass']);
                        header('Location: index.php');
                    exit();
```

}

Comment: se for `false` quer dizer que ele não possui a sessão, logo é desnecessário remove-la visto que não existe.

Comment: Eu destruiria a sessão, logo que a sessão só é encerrada com o fechamento do browser, outas aplicações podem ter sessões criadas com o mesmo nome e se não for destruída em algum momento pode não redirecionar a página, dessa forma eu tenho certeza que a sessão é encerrada. Mas fica a critério do nosso amigo, destruir a sessão ou não e redirecionar caso os dados sejam falsos.

Comment: Olá Igor, boa noite!
Eu criei um arquivo chamado protecao.php com o código que vc. recomendou, e ficou assim:
`<?php
if($userp == $login && $passp == $senha) {

    $_SESSION['login'] = $userp;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $passp;
    header('Location: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/painel/index.php');
    exit(); 
    }else{
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
    header('Location: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/index.php');
    exit(); 
}
?>`

Comment: Mas Igor, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/buziosne/public_html/admin/painel/index.php:2) in /home/buziosne/public_html/admin/protecao.php on line 6**

Tanto entrando com o login e senha ou direto pela URL.

O login e senha de acesso para teste é: Login - usuario / Senha - 123

Sou muito leigo em php se tu puderes me mostrar onde estou errando ficarei agradecido.

Endereço para acesso ao teste:
(http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/admin/painel/)

Obrigadão pela sua atenção.

Comment: Amigo, verifique se você iniciou a sessão, lembrado que a sessão deve esta sempre no top da página. Como você vai utilizar o header Location no meio da página, você deve utilizar antes do session_start() o ob_start() que deve ficar antes do session_start();

Comment: <?php
 ob_start();
    session_start();

    $user = 'igor';
    $pass = '123456';
    $userp = $_POST['user'];
    $passp = $_POST['pass'];
    
    if($userp == $user && $passp == $pass) {

     $_SESSION['user'] = $userp;
     $_SESSION['pass'] = $passp;
     header('Location: inserir.php');
     exit(); 
      }else{
     unset($_SESSION['user']);
     unset($_SESSION['pass']);
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit(); 
    }
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigos estou respondendo a minha própria pergunta, porque consegui resolver com a ajuda de um tutorial do YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yUMdFWrPJc (Que gostaria de compartilhar com os amigos), com algumas adaptações para o meu projeto, e vou publicar abaixo os códigos que criei para que o mesmo funcionasse.

Pagina de Login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><?php include "../conexao.php"; ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Painel Adm. - Login</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_login/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
$logotipo = $_POST['logotipo']; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topo");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<div id="logo" class="form bradius">
<div align="center" class="logo"><img src="../upload/<?php echo  $res['logotipo'] ;?>" width="auto" height="58" /></div>
<div class="acomodar">
<form name="enter" method="post" action="logar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="login">Login: </label><input id="login" type="text" class="txt bradius" name="login" value="" />
<label for="senha">Senha: </label><input  id="senha" type="password" class="txt bradius" name="senha" value="" />
<input type="submit" class="sb bradius" name="enter" value="Entrar" />
</form>
<!--acomodar-->
</div>
<!--login-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Página logar.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<?php include "../conexao.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Logando Usuário</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function logado(){
setTimeout("window.location='painel/index.php'", 5000); 
}

function deslogado(){
setTimeout("window.location='index.php'", 5000);    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$login = $_POST["login"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login' and senha = '$senha'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($row > 0){
$_SESSION["login"]=$_POST["login"];
$_SESSION["senha"]=$_POST["senha"];
    echo "<script>logado()</script>";
}else{
    echo "<center>Login ou Senha do usuário inválido! Tente Novamente!</center>";
    echo "<script>deslogado()</script>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Página restrito.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])){
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Página logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Página de acesso ao Painel index.php:

```
<?php include "../restrito.php"; ?>

<?php include "topo.php"; ?>
<?php include "cont.php"; ?>
```

Lembrando aos amigos que fiz o include da pagina restrito.php em todas as página que desejo que seja restrita ao usuário com acesso via login e senha, sem condições de acessa-las direto via url.

Agradeço a todos a atenção dispensada ao meu problema, e espero ajudar com essa solução que encontrei para que funcionasse a restrição via acesso direto pela URL.

Abraços à todos.