# Sistema de login com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, preciso fazer uma área administrativa, e obviamente preciso de um sistema de login e senha. Sei que já existem aqui, perguntas sobre este assunto, mas temo que elas estejam desatualizadas. Quero um jeito dentro do possível simples e seguro. Também não quero que ninguém faça nada pra mim, até por que estou aprendendo e óbviamente quero dominar isso, quero apenas que me dêem dicas de como fazer, links de referência e etc. Obrigado desde já.

O que eu tenho até agora:

```
<form action="submit" method="POST">
    <h1>LOGIN:</h1>
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <h1>SENHA:</h1>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">ENTRAR</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Além do html é interessante postar algum código alguma tentativa como você fez e talz para o pessoal dar as dicas alem disso

Comment: Quem votou como ampla demais poderia comentar o motivo disso.

Comment: Tiago, Infelizmente esta pergunta esta ampla demais para uma resposta direta e não baseada em opiniões, seria interessante se você tivesse uma dúvida especifica nesta questão de realizar login com php.  se você não sabe por onde começar o google pode te dar uma ajuda nisso, olhe um exemplo: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3561/criando-um-sistema-de-cadastro-e-login-com-php-e-mysql.aspx

Comment: Eu não votei, mas ela esta ampla demais mesmo!

Comment: Não acho que esteja ampla demais pois não pedí nenhuma resposta concreta, não pedí que fizessem nenhum código pra mim, pedí apenas dicas de por onde começar a estudar. @GabrielRodrigues

Comment: eu não votei porem existem muitas formas de fazer, caracterizando ampla demais. Se você colocasse algum codigo tipo estou indo por aqui ficaria mais facil pois ja teria um caminho. agora da forma que voce colocou foi tipo façam por mim da melhor forma possivel.

Comment: Existem respostas minhas para dúvidas nesse contexto de login, veja estas dúas elas se tratam de realizar um login mas são respostas bem diferentes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70758/acesso-somente-via-login-e-senha-inibindo-acesso-direto-via-url/70765#70765 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95352/login-com-cookie-ou-session-no-php5/95358#95358

Comment: Não, @Otto não quero que façam por mim, muito pelo contrário, desculpe se pareceu isso, mas quero exatamente o contrário, quero apenas que me direcionem por algum caminho em que eu possa fazer e aprender da melhor forma possível.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual o melhor jeito de fazer um sistema de login em senha com PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)

Comment: Acho boa a pergunta, especialmente à luz de algumas respostas, mas isso já foi perguntado antes. Se você acha que `Sei que já existem aqui, perguntas sobre este assunto, mas temo que elas estejam desatualizadas` precisa explicar e demonstrar o porquê.

Comment: O único problema dessas respostas é que sempre levam quem está aprendendo PHP para o lado do paradigma procedural. A maioria não sabe trabalhar de forma organizada com ele e cria grandes obras de arte com seus códigos, por isso a má reputação da linguagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Esqueça SHA1 e MD5

Antes de começar, é bom deixar claro. Não use nenhum desses métodos de criptografia. Você vai entender o porque no decorrer desta resposta.

## Informações importantes

Recomendo que leia [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php?rq=1) resposta, depois leia [esse](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish/) artigo do Thiago Belem, depois [esse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) artigo da própria documentação do PHP.

Os links acima irão mostrar porque você não deve utilizar sha1 ou MD5.

No caso do segundo link que passei, não só leia, mas execute o que foi ensinado e execute novamente até que você saiba o que está sendo feito. Depois disso, recomendo que também o processo utilizando as instruções do terceiro link, o `password_hash`

Não vou reinventar a roda aqui, até porque o primeiro link já tem tudo que você precisa saber e os demais são os exercícios de criptografia.

Vou lhe dar um exemplo de solução para o seu caso, simples e comentado para que você entenda. No exemplo irei utilizar o `password_hash`, que é o método mais seguro atualmente.

## Exemplo de uso

**No HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="login">Login</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button type="submit">Fazer login</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" <?php echo "value='" . $_SESSION['formKey'] . "'" ?>>
</form>
```

No `action` não precisa colocar nada, já que vamos usar a mesma página do formulário para validar os dados.

Se você leu o primeiro link que te passei, deve saber que o campo input do tipo `hidden` serve para dificultar `ataques do tipo CSRF` (Cross-site Request Forgery), onde o formulário só será validado se o valor do `hidden` for igual ao valor da `$_SESSION['formKey']`. Lembrando que essa `$_SESSION` deverá ser alterada a cada vez que a página for atualizada, depois de passar pela validação do método `$_POST`, claro. No código PHP você vai entender.

Recomendo que leia [esse](http://www.redesegura.com.br/2012/03/serie-ataques-os-ataques-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf/) artigo sobre ataques CSRF.

A questão dos labels, é apenas um aspecto de `UX design`, onde você permite que o usuário clique no label, e o foco seja direcionado ao input.

**No PHP**

```
<?php

    //Possibilita que trabalhemos com sessões, vai ser útil para validar o campo
    //hidden, e também para manter o usuário logado no sistema.
    //mas isso é outro ponto e não vou abordá-lo aqui.
    session_start();

    //Dados do banco
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '123456';
    $database = 'meusite';

    //Se conecta ao banco de dados
    $mysql = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_set_charset($mysql, 'utf8');

    //Se o usuário clicar em submit, ele faz uma requisição POST e aciona
    //essa condição
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        //Verifica se o valor do campo hidden bate com o valor da session.
        if (isset($_POST['hidden']) && $_POST['hidden'] == $_SESSION['formKey']) {

            //Verifica se existe um POST chamado login e senha respectivamente e,
            //se existir, remove os espaços no começo e final da string usando a função
            //trim() e atribui o valor deles as respectivas variáveis.
            //Se não existir, define o valor da variável como null.

            //Se não entendeu como funciona, pesquise sobre OPERADOR TERNÁRIO e função TRIM
            $login      = (isset($_POST['login'])) ? trim($_POST['login']) : null;
            $password   = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

            if (empty($login)) {
                //Se a variável $login estiver vazia, faça:
                echo 'Por favor, preencha o campo de login';
                exit;
            }
            if (empty($password)) {
                //Se a variável $password estiver vazia, faça:
                echo 'Por favor, preencha o campo de senha';
                exit;
            }

            //Antes de comparar qualquer dado com o banco, fazemos escape para dificultar
            //SQL injections.
            $login      = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $login);
            $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $password);

            //Seleciona os campos login e password na tabela usuarios, cujo login seja
            //igual ao login informado no formulário.
            //Lembre-se de marcar a coluna login no banco de dados como UNIQUE ID
            //para que não seja possível existir mais de um login igual.
            $result = mysqli_query($mysql,
            "SELECT `login`, `password` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `login` = '" . $login . "'");

            if(!mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                echo "Usuário não encontrado";
                exit;
            } else {
                //Coloca os dados retornados pelo banco em um array chamado $data
                while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $data[] = $r;
                }
            }

            //Chegando neste ponto, entede-se que o login informado existe, agora temos que
            //validar a senha.

            //Vamos supor que você usou password_hash para criptografar a senha no
            //momento do cadastro do usuário.

            if (password_verify($password, $data[0]['password'])) {
                echo "Logado com sucesso!";
            } else {
                echo "Senha incorreta!";
                exit;
            }

            //Fazendo isso, estamos dizendo pro PHP verificar se a senha informada
            //corresponde ao hash (senha criptografada) que estava no banco.
        }
    }

    //Toda vez que ele atualizar a página, o value do campo hidden será alterado
    //Abaixo fizemos o sha1 de um número randomico usando a função rand().
    $_SESSION['formKey'] = sha1(rand());

    //Eu usei sha1, porque? Simples. O valor do campo hidden não tem importancia
    //pra gente. Ele não precisa ser seguro, até porque ele será visível caso
    //o usuário clique em visualiar o código fonte, ele só precisa mudar e ser
    //impossível de se acertar num "chute".
?>
```

A receita do bolo está aí, basta usá-la.

Comment: Profissional demais a resposta ++1!

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira, usar `mysqli_real_escape_string()` com `mysqli_*` não é mais necessário,  além disso você está passando variável diretamente no SQL, o que não é muito seguro. [Veja aqui as soluções](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) que existem dentro do `mysqli_*`.

Comment: No site do MySQL [tem outro exemplo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-stmt.bind-param.html)

Comment: Realmente, muito bom esse método que você me passou. Obrigado pela dica :)

Answer (score 6):

Algo que eu vejo muito nos tutoriais que encontro na internet é que eles separam a configuração da apresentação, mas não usam [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) como a gente vê na maior parte dos sites que o pessoal cria hoje em dia, eles simplesmente separam esses ficheiros através de diretórios, aí você pode programar sem usar [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) e deixar o site simples.

```
\- root
 + - configuracao
    - includes
    - conexão
 + site
    - css
    - imagens
    - javascript
    - index.php
    - login.php
    + administração
      - css
      - imagens
      - javascript
      - index.php
      - login.php
      - apagar.php
      - cadastrar.php
```

Você poderia optar por uma estrutura semelhante e deixar sua aplicação simples e segura. Separando o login de administrador dos logins de usuários normais, e separando também as tabelas de usuários com a dos administradores no banco de dados.

Você  deve restringir os privilégios para os usuários dessas tabelas, sanitizar os dados antes de serem gravados no banco de dados, e também os dados que os usuários e administradores digitam para fazer o login no sistema ou alterar dados no banco de dados.

Você pode usar essas funções de [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) pra criptografar as senhas antes de gravar no banco de dados.

Se você quiser mais dicas, existem também esses posts aqui:

[Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

[Qual a melhor maneira de criar um sistema de login com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php)

[Lembrar usuário com segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33664/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-seguran%C3%A7a/33684#33684)

Comment: Muito obrigado, irei estudar e achei ótima suas recomendações. :)

Answer (score 2):

Dê uma olhada nesse blog:
[login - OO](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criando-um-sistema-de-login-com-php-e-mysql/).
Um exemplo orientado a objeto usando PHP.
Para senha use SHA1: [Senhas](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-md5-sha1-e-base64/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou olhar sim!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo dar uma estudada também em ***MD5*** (ou SHA1 como nossa amiga @Bia mencionou). 
Também olhe sobre ***Validação de Login por Sessions***.
E, se quiseres, dê uma olhada em SQL Inject para aprender um pouco mais das falhas de segurança que AINDA existem em muitos sites.
Bons estudos!

PS: já existe um tópico similar: [Melhor jeito de fazer um sistema de login e senha com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-o-melhor-jeito-de-fazer-um-sistema-de-login-em-senha-com-php?rq=1)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas!! Irei estudar tudo isso. Valeu amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

**Resumidamente:**
Como você está começando agora, o primeiro passo que posso sugerir para estudar, antes de fazer um sistema de login e senha, é seguir a normalização das [**PSRs**](http://www.php-fig.org), afinal, não queremos mais códigos mal feitos por aí.

O segundo passo é, sempre que possível, consultar a [**Documentação Oficial do PHP**](http://php.net/).

[**Este site**](http://br.phptherightway.com/#site-header) tem bastante informação para quem precisa aprender a desenvolver com PHP.

Para fazer um sistema de login, você vai precisar basicamente de:

1. [**Conexão com banco de dados**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
2. [**Configuração de sessão**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
3. [**Criar usuário, senha e um hash**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Para as páginas que você tiver restrição de acesso, você deverá criar níveis de acesso para os usuários, uma maneira de fazer isso é dando peso ao usuário, no exemplo abaixo, irei dar 3 pesos, 0 - bloqueado, 1 - editor, 2 - administrador.

**Tabela usuário:**

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  `salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Dados do Usuário';
```

**Tabela do perfil do usuário:**

```
  CREATE TABLE `Roles` (
  `id_role` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_role`),
  KEY `fk_Roles_1_idx` (`fk_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Roles_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user`) REFERENCES `User` (`id_user`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Níveis de acesso do Usuário';
```

Agora, para verificar os níveis de acesso, você faria uma consulta desse tipo, pegando todos os usuários que não estão bloqueados (`0`):

```
function createPassword($pass)
{
 //salve isso no User.password 
  return password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

function checkLogin($user, $pass, $dbh)
{

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Users.password as pass_hash AND Users.username :=user");
$sth->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$resultHash = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if (validPassword($pass, $resultHash->pass_hash)) {

   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  Users.id_user as 'ID',
                                 Users.username,
                                 Roles.name,
                                 Roles.level
                         FROM    Users
                         INNER JOIN Roles ON
                                 (User.id_user=Roles.fk_user
                                  AND  Roles.level != 0)
                         WHERE   Users.username :=user
                      ");
   $sth->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $sth->execute();
   $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   createSession($result);
 }
}

function validPassword($pass, $hash)
{
  return password_verify($pass, $hash);
}
```

Então basicamente, você irá verificar o login. E assim que confirmar, você cria a sessão:

```
function createSession($dados)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['level_user'] = $dados['level'];
    $_SESSION['ip_user'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $_SESSION['tipo_user'] = $dados['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $dados['username'];
}
```

E depois verifica se o usuário está logado e o nível dele:

```
 function checkSession($nivel)
 {
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['level_user'] == $nivel && $_SESSION['ip_user'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_DDR'] &&  isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
           //permitido
    } else {
          //não permitido
    }           
 }
```

Comment: Ótimo, irei estudar e também estudar sua resposta, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo ;)